# okhttp3 - обрыв интернета. приложение вылетает

Tags: android, android-studio, okhttp

Дайте совет что делать, либо что почитать. Использую библиотеку okhttp3. Мне надо в приложении получить данные в формате json от моего сервера.

Делаю так:

```
String urlAllow = mSettings.getString(APP_PREFERENCES_SCRIPT, "") + "allow.php";
        String jsonAllow = "{\"imei\":\""+imei+"\", \"tel\":\""+mSettings.getString(APP_PREFERENCES_LOGIN, "")+"\"}";

        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, jsonAllow);

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(urlAllow)
                .post(body)
                .build();

        try {
            Response responseAllow = client1.newCall(request).execute();
            assert responseAllow.body() != null;
            resultAllow = Objects.requireNonNull(responseAllow.body()).string();
        }
        catch( Exception e ){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Все работает прекрасно и на всех устройствах. 
Да, забыл показать, что прописано в **client1**

```
private OkHttpClient client1 = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build();
```

Дело в том, что при плохой связи с интернетом, я так предполагаю, происходит обрыв и приложение вылетает. Естественно, что отловить ошибку не могу, так как в этот короткий промежуток времени (пока получаются данные из сети), я не успеваю рубануть инет.

Как можно избежать, либо фикс какой сделать, что при обрыве связи, либо просто вывести сообщение, что связь оборвалась, либо (это в идеале), заставить еще раз делать запрос на сервер?

Перед запросом, я естественно, сначала проверяю подключение устройства к инету, и вафлю, и сотовый инет. Конечно, если связь есть, то приложение уже пытается получить данные. Что делать, если в этот момент происходит обрыв?

Comment: Полный кусок кода пожалуйста, т.к. можно подумать что работу с сетью выполняете в основном потоке. У кого падает приложение? Откуда уверенность что проблема именно в этом куске кода?

Comment: нет. не в основном потоке. если именно это спросил, значит уверен в этом. мои пользователи именно с этой проблемой сталкиваются.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще, перед тем как проверять тело ответа и обрабатывать его, проверяйте код ответа (responseAllow.code() == 200) или же более расширенно - responseAllow.isSuccessful(). В responseAllow.message() можно увидеть текст ответа. Возможно в теле ответа в вашем случае содержится совсем не структурированные (JSON) данные и при `Objects.requireNonNull(responseAllow.body())` как раз и происходит ошибка. Обрабатывать тело ответа нужно только если есть твердая уверенность, что запрос выполнился удачно и получили данные именно в том виде, в каком ожидали.

PS. В отлове разных ошибок в приложении очень сильно помогает [Crashlytics](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics), можете ознакомиться с этим инструментом или аналогичными инструментами.